# handling csv cell line breaks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

```
locals {
  dns_data = <<-CSV
  RecordType,RecordName,RecordZone,RecordZoneId,RecordValue
  A,something.example.com,something,zoneid,"x.x.x.x \n x.x.x.x"
  CSV

  dns_records = csvdecode(local.dns_data)
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "route53_entry" {
  for_each = {for record in local.dns_records : record.RecordName => record}
  name = each.value.RecordName
  type = each.value.RecordType
  zone_id = each.value.RecordZoneId
  ttl = 60
  records = [each.value.RecordValue]
}
```

I'm trying to create the r53 entries inside a zone using a CSV. How to handle the line breaks inside a cell? My A record cord can have multiple values, tried multiple ways with no luck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: " tried multiple ways with no luck." - is not specific. What exactly did you try? Why it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: tried putting the RecordValue inside double quotes with actual line break, \n, escaping quotes etc.. the plan show this   # aws_route53_record.route53_entry["xxxxx"] will be created
 
      + records         = [
          + <<-EOT
                x.x.x.x
                y.y.y.y
            EOT,
        ]
      + ttl             = 60
      + type            = "A"
      + zone_id         = "xxxxxxx"
    }  and fails with [Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: ARRDATANotSingleField (Value contains spaces) when I apply.

Comment: does it make sense @Marcin

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I'm working on something similar / haven't yet coded anything but am thinking ahead for pitfalls like this one.  I also had a query around multiple DNS records with the same RecordName and how `for_each` could handle that; did you experience that issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247216/using-terraforms-for-each-with-data-that-doesnt-have-a-unique-key